# angularjs-uirouter $state.go Error as .go undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Here imgetting Error in `$statechangStart`    Here im trying to checking my credentials in $statechageStart

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $stateProvider
         .state('Login',{
                url:'/LoginService',
                templateUrl: '/ApiClient/Home/LoginPage.html',
                controller:'LoginController'

            })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
    })

     .run(function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options, $scope, $state) {
                debugger;
                if (toState.module == "Private" && sessionStorage.getItem('employee')!=null) {}

                else {
                    event.preventDefault();
                     $state.go('Login');
                }
```

Comment: Would you mind including your app.config?

Comment: @Tom please Review my update code

Comment: what error you got?

Comment: @Mavlarn .go is undefind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject **`$state`** to your .run , otherwise it is undefined

```
.run(function ($rootScope, $state)
```

**EDIT**

It's a bad practice to use $state.go in $stateChangeStart event. For your purposes, you'd better apply the state.go after setting a timeout

```
   $timeout($state.go.bind(null, 'Login'), 3000);
```

Comment: Error as Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: This Error im Getting when i inject ($rootScope, $state)   and remove from $stateChangesStart